# Operand types do not match

Tags: ассемблер

Ошибка в 13 строке. Мне необходимо получившийся результат записать в num. Я понимаю, что num и al имеют разные типы, но я не могу понять как это исправить.

```
 .MODEL Large,C
        .data
        Extrn   aaaS:byte,cccS:byte,bbbS:byte,denom:word,num:word,result:word;
        .code
        Public  Lab3S
Lab3s   proc    far
        mov al,22
    div cccS
    mov bl,3
    mul bbbS
    add al,bl
    mov num,al

        ret
Lab3S   endp
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте копирование с расширением. Есть два варианта - обнуление старших бит:

```
movzx num, al
```

и расширение с сохранением знака:

```
movsx num, al
```

Раз используется `div` (беззнаковое деление), предположу что в данном случае нужен первый вариант.